# PySpark SQL subqueries not supporting

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am trying to execute the below SQL syntax in PySpark.
The query is supposed to return the success rate of the subscription (total subscription / total_entries).
table_name = banking
columns name:
'y'(subscription purchased) contains 'yes' and 'no' as a data value.

Query excuted:

spark.sql(" select(x.total_subscribed / y.total_entries) as success_rate
from (select count(*)as total_subscribed  from banking_tbl  where y ='yes')x, (select count(*) as total_entries  from banking_tbl)y ").show()

I am using two  inner subqueries :

the first  inner query below returns the total customer who purchased subscription:

(select count(*)as total_subscribed from banking_tbl where y ='yes')x)

And the second query returns the total customer from the table:

(select count(*) as total_entries from banking_tbl)y ")

and the outer query to get the rate of subscription:
( total customer who purchased subscription / total customers )

select(x.total_subscribed / y.total_entries) as success_rate

But I get an error as follow:

"use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these\nrelations, or: enable implicit cartesian products
by setting the configuration\nvariable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;'"

sample data:
+---+------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
|age|job         |marital |education|default|balance|housing|loan|contact|day|month|duration|campaign|pdays|previous|poutcome|y  |
+---+------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
|58 |management  |married |tertiary |no     |2143   |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |261     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|44 |technician  |single  |secondary|no     |29     |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |151     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|33 |entrepreneur|married |secondary|no     |2      |yes    |yes |unknown|5  |may  |76      |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|47 |blue-collar |married |unknown  |no     |1506   |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |92      |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|33 |unknown     |single  |unknown  |no     |1      |no     |no  |unknown|5  |may  |198     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|35 |management  |married |tertiary |no     |231    |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |139     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|28 |management  |single  |tertiary |no     |447    |yes    |yes |unknown|5  |may  |217     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|42 |entrepreneur|divorced|tertiary |yes    |2      |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |380     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|58 |retired     |married |primary  |no     |121    |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |50      |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|43 |technician  |single  |secondary|no     |593    |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |55      |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|41 |admin.      |divorced|secondary|no     |270    |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |222     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|29 |admin.      |single  |secondary|no     |390    |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |137     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|53 |technician  |married |secondary|no     |6      |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |517     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|58 |technician  |married |unknown  |no     |71     |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |71      |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
|57 |services    |married |secondary|no     |162    |yes    |no  |unknown|5  |may  |174     |1       |-1   |0       |unknown |no |
+---+------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is simpler to use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when y = 'yes' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from banking_tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, your query format is not correct
spark.sql(''' select subscription_count/total_count as success_rate from (select (select count(*) from banking_tbl) as total_count,(select count(*) from banking_tbl  where subscription='Y' ) as subscription_count )''').show()
how it executed please check the link for output https://knowledges.co.in/q-a/